# Union in select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, union

Here I want to show count for `im.eindex` at the end. SO, for this I use `union all` for this but the result shows like there is total per record.

```
select
            '' Field1,
              '' Field2, 
              'Comp' GField1,   
                ltrim(rtrim(cm.CName))  CName,
                count(im.eindex) Emp
        From    Log l, 
                IMaster im, 
                cmaste cm 
        where   cm.cindex=im.cindex
                and im.iindex=sms.iindex
                and im.Month = 10
                and im.year = 2017
                and cm.type
                group by cm.CName

    union all 

            select  
            '' Field1,
              '' Field2, 
              'Comp' GField1,   
                ‘total’  CName,
                sum(im.eindex) Emp
                From    Log l, 
                IMaster im, 
                cmaste cm 
        where   cm.cindex=im.cindex
                and im.iindex=sms.iindex
                and im.Month = 10
                and im.year = 2017
                and cm.type
                group by cm.CName
```

Output from above query is

```
Field1  Field2  GField1 CName   Employees
                        ABC COM   91
                        XYZ COMP    15
                       Total    7759562
                       Total    21211214
```

Comment: It looks like XYProblem. Post your real data + desired output. It looks like you want to prepare some sort of report, that is why you add rows with aggregation. I would suggest to use `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS()` with correct agg function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the last `group by` statement as we want to show the total of all `CName`:

```
select
            '' Field1,
              '' Field2, 
              'Comp' GField1,   
                ltrim(rtrim(cm.CName))  CName,
                count(im.eindex) Emp
        From    Log l, 
                IMaster im, 
                cmaste cm 
        where   cm.cindex=im.cindex
                and im.iindex=sms.iindex
                and im.Month = 10
                and im.year = 2017
                and cm.type
                group by cm.CName

    union all 

            select  
            '' Field1,
              '' Field2, 
              'Comp' GField1,   
                ‘total’  CName,
                count(im.eindex) Emp
                From    Log l, 
                IMaster im, 
                cmaste cm 
        where   cm.cindex=im.cindex
                and im.iindex=sms.iindex
                and im.Month = 10
                and im.year = 2017
                and cm.type
```

Having the `group by` in the second `SELECT` means we are again showing the `SUM` per `cm.Cname`.

You can even simplify this:

```
select
    '' Field1,
        '' Field2, 
        'Comp' GField1,   
        ISNULL(ltrim(rtrim(cm.CName)), 'Total')  CName,
        count(im.eindex) Emp
From    Log l, 
        IMaster im, 
        cmaste cm 
where   cm.cindex=im.cindex
        and im.iindex=sms.iindex
        and im.Month = 10
        and im.year = 2017
        and cm.type
        group by GROUPING SETS
        (
            (cm.CName)
            ,()
        )
```